# neo4j data integrity?

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

I have some questions about Neo4j and data integrity!
As under Neo4j data integrity is ensured? And since all ACID properties are supported, as are implemented. So atomicity, consistency, isolation, durability?

Maybe one or information sources on this?
Thank you in advance for

best regards

Answer (score 1):

start here:
http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/introduction-highlights.html

since i don't understand exactly your question, could you please post your goal - what are you about to do with neo4j, and if any what is your current technology you are using for your goal now? than maybe i could answer whether it's possible or not.

Comment: Ok, the goal is to examine the data integrity of Neo4j whether and how foreign keys and referential integrity can be implemented. As the ACID properties to be implemented. Best with simple examples ...

Comment: long story short: yes, neo4j is capable of handling the ACID properties. if you still need to explain it with examples, please read the whole manual. it would take me several hours to write such a long tutorial. anyway, in case you know the topic (ACID in databases + graphs), you need no explanation actually. in case you dont know much about it, you will still need to go through a lot of materials.

Comment: ok ACID is a long story, but have you any examples for Foreign Key oder the ref. integrity?

Comment: actually, design of a graph db itself simply erases the foreign key area. in traditional sql db you are using foreign keys to match the same item in different tables. in graph db you have just the original item, and any foreign key representation is just a relation from that original node to another. my fast google search gave me this as an example: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/neo4j/R8_ipnnSGBM